# Sidebar menu implementation on iOS like Facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sidebar

I want to create side-bar menu like in Facebook iPhone app in iOS 6.

How can I create it?

I'm new to this iPhone development.

Please give me some pointers or tell me some basic tutorial that I can follow step by step to achieve it.

Comment: try below URLS: [URL1](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mfsidemenu) [URL2](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jasidepanels) And by the way you can check [www.cocoacontrols.com](https://www.cocoacontrols.com) web site, it is a pretty good.

Comment: @zeeshan shaikh - There are so many answers.If you accept any of the answer as useful it'll help others to identify the solution easily

Answer (score 39):

We can easily do it by ourselves. It's so easy.

The approach I explain here is being used in my app.

### objective:

> When a button is pressed in title bar a side bar has to slide in and
>   out from left side.

### Steps:

> 1) *Create a view controller(home) and two nsObject
>   classes(sidebar,main)*
>
> 2) *add a tool bar on view controller*
>
> 3) *In sidebar (Left side view):*
>
> i) Build a uiview(to be added on vc) with desired sidebar width within that add views as needed for your project
>
> ii) then create button and make it as property because it's target
>   events will have to occur in view controller
>
> iii) you have to have two CGRects for both button and the resultant
>   view one CGrect is for expanded state another CGrect is for collapsed
>
> iv) as far as button is cocerned it's x is sidebarwidth-buttonwidth
>   for expanded state and it's x is 0+buttonwidth for collapsed state and
>   as far as view is concerned it's x is 0 for expanded state and it's x
>   is -sidebarwidth for collapsed state
>
> 4) *In main(right side view):*
>
> i) Build a UIView and add it to UiscollView(to be added on vc)
>
> ii) UIView will have two CGREcts for UIscrollView one for expanded and
>   one for collapsed
>
> iii) UIview's x is 0 y is 0 width is 1024 and height is 726(landscape
>   view height-toolbar width on vc)
>
> iv) On Collapsed time uIscrollview's x is sidebarwidth y is 42(vc'tool
>   bar height) and width is 1024-sidebarwidth and height is same as
>   uiview's
>
> v) on expanded time Uiscrollview's x is 0 and width becomes 1024
>
> vi) Uiscrollview content size always should be 1024,726 as we need
>   scrolling if the size is shrunk than this
>
> 5) *In view controller (home page):*
>
> i) add both the side bar and main in home
>
> ii) then add and event for the button in sidebar and then add it on
>   the tool bar usign addsubview method
>
> iii) In the button touch event call toggle events inside
>
> ```
>  -(void)OnCollapsibleExtenderTouchUpInside
> {
>    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
>
>     [sideBarObj ToggleVuPosition];
>
>     [mainVuObj ToggleVuSize];
>
>  }];
>
> }
> ```
>
> The below code works for me..(I just renamed some field for my own
>   sake)

**To understand the below code better:**

> 1) The View controller name is Home and side bar name is side bar and
>   right side area name is Main
>
> 2) I have wrote the coding for landscape alone...you can customize it
>   for portrait also one use it.

***Side bar:***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SideBar : NSObject
{
UIView *vuSideBar;

UIScrollView *scrollVuSideBar;

UIImageView *imgProfilePicture;

CGRect rectVuSideBar,rectExpandedScrollVuSideBar,rectCollapsedScrollVuSideBar,rectImgProfilePicture,rectExpandedBtnCollapsibleExtender,rectCollapsedBtnCollapsibleExtender;

 int sideBarWidth,sideBarHeight;
}

@property(strong,nonatomic)UIButton *btnCollapsibleExtender;

-(id)initWithParent:(UIView *)vuParent andToolBar:(UIToolbar *)toolBarParent;

-(void)ToggleVuPosition;

@end
```

***Side bar implementation:***

```
 #import "SideBar.h"

@interface  SideBar()

-(void)initRects;

-(void)initVus;

-(void)initOtherIvars;

-(void)AddViewsOnHierarchy;

-(void)AddToParentVu:(UIView *)ParentVu;

-(void)OnCollapsibleExtenderTouchUpInside;

@end

@implementation SideBar

@synthesize btnCollapsibleExtender;

-(id)initWithParent:(UIView *)vuParent andToolBar:(UIToolbar  *)toolBarParent
{
 self = [super init]; //calls init because UIResponder has no custom init methods
 if (self)
 {
    [self initOtherIvars];

    [self initRects];

    [self initVus];

    [self AddViewsOnHierarchy];

    [self AddToParentVu:vuParent];

    [self AddToParentToolbar:toolBarParent];

   }
   return self;
 }

 -(void)initOtherIvars
 {
   NSLog(@"initOtherIvars");

   sideBarWidth=300;

   sideBarHeight=768;
 }

 -(void)initRects
 {
  NSLog(@"initRects");

  rectExpandedScrollVuSideBar=CGRectMake(0,42,sideBarWidth,sideBarHeight);

 rectCollapsedScrollVuSideBar=CGRectMake(-sideBarWidth,42,sideBarWidth,sideBarHeight);

rectExpandedBtnCollapsibleExtender=CGRectMake(sideBarWidth-30,6,30,30);

rectCollapsedBtnCollapsibleExtender=CGRectMake(6,6,30,30);

rectVuSideBar=CGRectMake(0,0,sideBarWidth,sideBarHeight);

rectImgProfilePicture=CGRectMake(5,5,sideBarWidth-10,200);
 }

 -(void)initVus
 {
  NSLog(@"initVus");

   scrollVuSideBar=[[UIScrollView  alloc]initWithFrame:rectExpandedScrollVuSideBar];

   [scrollVuSideBar setContentSize:CGSizeMake(sideBarWidth,sideBarHeight)];


   btnCollapsibleExtender=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:rectExpandedBtnCollapsibleExtender];

   UIImage *imgCollapsibleExtender=[UIImage imageNamed:@"SideBarExpandCollapse.png"];

   [btnCollapsibleExtender setImage:imgCollapsibleExtender forState:UIControlStateNormal];


   vuSideBar=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rectVuSideBar];

   [vuSideBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];


   imgProfilePicture=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:rectImgProfilePicture];

   UIImage *imgDefaultProfile=[UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultProfileImage.png"];

   [imgProfilePicture setImage:imgDefaultProfile];

  }

 -(void)AddViewsOnHierarchy
{
   NSLog(@"AddViewsOnHierarchy");

   [vuSideBar addSubview:imgProfilePicture];

   [scrollVuSideBar addSubview:vuSideBar];
 }

 -(void)AddToParentVu:(UIView *)ParentVu
 {
   NSLog(@"AddToParent vu");

  [ParentVu addSubview:scrollVuSideBar];
 }

 -(void)AddToParentToolbar:(UIToolbar *)ParentToolBar
 {
  NSLog(@"AddToParent toolbar");

 [ParentToolBar addSubview:btnCollapsibleExtender];
 }

 -(void)ToggleVuPosition
 {
 switch ((int)scrollVuSideBar.frame.origin.x)
 {
     case 0:

        scrollVuSideBar.frame=rectCollapsedScrollVuSideBar;

             btnCollapsibleExtender.frame=rectCollapsedBtnCollapsibleExtender;

        break;

      default:

        scrollVuSideBar.frame=rectExpandedScrollVuSideBar;

          btnCollapsibleExtender.frame=rectExpandedBtnCollapsibleExtender;

        break;
   }
 }

@end
```

***Main(Right side view):***

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 @interface MainView : NSObject
 {
  UIView *vuMain;

  UIScrollView *scrollVuMain;

  CGRect  rectVuMain,rectScrollVuMainExpanded,rectScrollVuMainCollpased;

  int mainWidth,mainHeight,sideBarWidth,HeaderBarHeight;
 }

 -(id)initWithParent:(UIView *)vuParent;

 -(void)ToggleVuSize;
 @end
```

***Main(Right side view) implementation:***

```
#import "MainView.h"

@interface MainView ()

-(void)initRects;

-(void)initVus;

-(void)initOtherIvars;

-(void)AddViewsOnHierarchy;

-(void)AddToParentVu:(UIView *)ParentVu;

@end

@implementation SGGI_MainView

-(id)initWithParent:(UIView *)vuParent
{
  self = [super init]; //calls init because UIResponder has no custom init methods
  if (self)
  {
    [self initOtherIvars];

    [self initRects];

    [self initVus];

    [self AddViewsOnHierarchy];

    [self AddToParentVu:vuParent];
   }
   return self;
 } 

-(void)initRects
{
rectVuMain=CGRectMake(0,0,1024,726);

       rectScrollVuMainExpanded=CGRectMake(0,HeaderBarHeight,mainWidth,mainHeight-HeaderBarHeight);

  rectScrollVuMainCollpased=CGRectMake(sideBarWidth,HeaderBarHeight,mainWidth-sideBarWidth,mainHeight-HeaderBarHeight);
}

-(void)initVus
{
 scrollVuMain=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:rectScrollVuMainCollpased];

 [scrollVuMain setContentSize:CGSizeMake(mainWidth,mainHeight-HeaderBarHeight)];

 vuMain=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rectVuMain];

 UILabel *lbl=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,30)];

 [lbl setText:@"Details123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz987654321abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz9876"];

 [vuMain addSubview:lbl];


}

-(void)initOtherIvars
{
 NSLog(@"initOtherIvars");

 mainWidth=1024;

 mainHeight=768;

 sideBarWidth=300;

 HeaderBarHeight=42;

}

-(void)AddViewsOnHierarchy
{
 [scrollVuMain addSubview:vuMain];
}

  -(void)AddToParentVu:(UIView *)ParentVu
 {
   [ParentVu addSubview:scrollVuMain];
 }

  -(void)ToggleVuSize
 {

 switch ((int)scrollVuMain.frame.size.width)
 {
    case 1024:

        scrollVuMain.frame=rectScrollVuMainCollpased;

        break;

    default:

        scrollVuMain.frame=rectScrollVuMainExpanded;

        break;
  }
}

@end
```

***Home(Embedding the above two one a VC):***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Home : UIViewController

@end
```

***Home implementation:***

```
#import "Home.h"

#import "sideBar.h"

#import "Main.h"

@interface Home ()
{
 sideBar *sideBarObj;

 Main *mainVuObj;

 UIToolbar *HeaderBarObj;
 }

 -(void)AddSideBar;

 -(void)AddMainView;

 -(void)AddHeaderBar;

 -(void)AddCollapsibleExtenderEvent;

 -(void)OnCollapsibleExtenderTouchUpInside;

@end

@implementation Home

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
 self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
 if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
 }
  return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

 [self AddHeaderBar];

 [self AddSideBar];

  [self AddMainView];

 [self AddCollapsibleExtenderEvent];
}

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

-(void)AddHeaderBar
 {
  HeaderBarObj=[[UIToolbar  alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,1024,42)];

  [self.view addSubview:HeaderBarObj];
 }

-(void)AddSideBar
{
 sideBarObj=[[SideBar alloc]initWithParent:self.view andToolBar:HeaderBarObj];
}

-(void)AddMainView
{
 mainVuObj=[[MainView alloc]initWithParent:self.view];
}

-(void)AddCollapsibleExtenderEvent
{
SEL   selCollapsibleTouch=@selector(OnCollapsibleExtenderTouchUpInside);

 [sideBarObj.btnCollapsibleExtender addTarget:self action:selCollapsibleTouch forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)OnCollapsibleExtenderTouchUpInside
{
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    [sideBarObj ToggleVuPosition];

    [mainVuObj ToggleVuSize];

 }];

}

@end
```

The above code can be customized further by without using main and adding the code for that in Home view controller likewise one can avoid a separate class for sidebar and include that in home viewcontroller itself.

As far as when user presses button in sidebar, for changes in main view you can use protocol delegates or we can have the buttons in sidebar as property and add events in view controller.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Tried this but having problem drawing up the storyboard any help?

Comment: @Duraiamuthan I'm lost. So theres no way I can get a quick run through of its implementation?

Comment: @Daniel You know we can code without using Interface builders as well.(This code will work using Interface Builder as well but that's not necessary).I haven't tried this with Storyboard I am willing to help u use this without storyboards.Just read the above answer clearly and try it as a sample project.Tell me where you encounter the problem I'll guide you.

Comment: It would have been nice if you had your sample project or git repo link instead of such a lengthy answer!

Comment: @rohan-patel soon I will add it in Github and post the link so that one can try faster

Comment: Have you posted this to GitHub yet?

Comment: @MikeFlynn Not yet I couldn't find free time to do this..once I have enough free time I will post it in github for sure !

Comment: Have you posted this to github??

Comment: @SurajSukale - Not so far

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of implementations but I will suggest you [JTRevealSidebarDemo](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTRevealSidebarDemo) its simple and easy to customize, you can also use [ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) or [JASidePanels](https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels).
JASidePanels is well documented and has basic examples for new developers like you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InteractiveSideMenu](https://github.com/handsomecode/InteractiveSideMenu) library written in Swift. It's quite good documented and has a lot of customizations.