# custom sidebar in ios7

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, sidebar

i am new in iOS development and facing little issue.i don't know this approach is good or bad but i not want to used any third party.I want to make sidebar like Facebook sidebar and my code is

```
- (IBAction)basicProfile:(id)sender {

    menuViewController *destVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuView"];


    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
    [animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromLeft];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
    CGRect view = self.view.frame;
    view.origin.x = 280;




    if(self.view.frame.origin.x > 100 )
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void *)(self.scrollView)];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
        NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.y);
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,568);
        [UIView commitAnimations];

    }

    else{
        [self.showView setHidden:NO];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:(__bridge void *)(self.scrollView)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.y);
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(280,0,320,568);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.view addSubview:destVC.view]; // this line added menuView to profile view but not on sidebar 
    }
}
```

i have two uiview in storyborad one is profile and other is menuViewController.why menuView not loaded properly
[result of above code](http://screencast.com/t/Mt9xy9ufJcaX)

Comment: +1 : ***i not want to used any third party***

Comment: no :( I am still searching but for temporary i used this CDRTranslucentSideBar library.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 01:** Basically what you need is a viewController and 2 views (1 for sidebar and another the main view.)

**Step 02 :** You would than require to add both these views to the View Controller.

**Step 03 :** And than add a button to toggle using below:

-

```
(void)OnCollapsibleExtenderTouchUpInside
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

    [sideBarObj ToggleVuPosition];

    [mainVuObj ToggleVuSize];

 }];

}
```

**Note :** There is already a explanation on stack overflow

You can follow this one:
[Sidebar menu implementation on iOS like Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17019612/sidebar-menu-implementation-on-ios-like-facebook)

If your requirement is different, Do post comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches to do this:

1. Using 2 UIViews on the Same controller. You can add your MenuView along with your view and initial keep it hidden. Use a button to toggle to show/hide the Menu. It will be just like xview.hidden = TRUE / xview.hidden = FALSE to show/hide the view. You can use animation to give it a menu like appearance.
2. Use a different view controller for MenuDisplay and add it to the current view controllers like [xview addsubView:menuview.view] and [menuview.view removefromsuperview]